# C# Win forms what object to use to display many videos on main window

Tags: c#, .net, controls, panel

I have 15 Windows.control objects that play video, I need to make a tile that displays 15 videos on the gui.
The videos are added to a panel. What is the best way to store those controls in order to divide the screen to 15 and present them all at once ?
The number 15 is pre-define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them to a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx).

You can change the `FlowDirection` and `WrapContents` properties to lay out the panels in the order you want.